# How to replace python 2.7 to 3.6 in a conda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I created a conda environment named AAA with python 2.7 long ago and I want to update the python to 3.6 without any change of other packages in AAA. I try `conda install python=3.6` in AAA, but all packages were emptied. What should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to reinstall packages for python 3.7. So it's better way to create new venv under 3.7. you can you `pip freeze` to get the list of installed packages and put it into requirements.txt file. then use it with `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` command. This will install them

more to that there's pip3 specially for python3.* which installs compatible packages.

BTW be aware that python2 code is not compatible with python3

Comment: I strongly recommend against this. `pip` will only pick up Python packages, but Conda environments often involve additional libraries that `pip` will not see.  Mixing `pip` and `conda` is strongly discouraged (see ["Using Pip in a Conda Environment"](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)).

Comment: agree. using conda is preferable. but anyway reinstalling is necessary

Answer (score 0):

[As @StanislavLipovenko pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57535405/570918), Python 2.7 packages can't run under Python 3.6 (they're installed to a different `site-packages` directory and usually aren't co-compatible), so you need a fresh install.

One option is to export your env configuration as a YAML:

```
conda env export -n my_py27_env --no-builds > my_env.yaml
```

Edit the line with `- python=2.7.*` to `- python=3.6`.  Then create a new env from this:

```
conda env create -f my_env.yaml -n my_py36_env
```

You may have some hiccups getting all the packages listed in the YAML to install, especially if your original env is quite old. For example, a package that had a Python 2.7 version may never have released that same version for Python 3.6. You can always soften the requirements by deleting the version numbers in the YAML for packages that present such barriers.  This is simply the unavoidable cost of transitioning.